# IONIC 5 empty FormData

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, form-data

I am performing a user profile, however when creating the FormData for sending it is being generated empty, even with all other fields having values. Below is the code cadastro.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { AlertController, ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PictureSourceType, Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';


import { CadastroService } from 'src/app/services/cadastro.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './cadastro.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastro.page.scss'],
})
export class CadastroPage implements OnInit {
  public registerForm: FormGroup

  constructor(
    private cadastroService: CadastroService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private ActionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
    private camera: Camera,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      foto: [''],
      nome: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      cpf: ['', Validators.required],
      telefone: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      conf_pass: ['', Validators.required]
    })

  }


  cadastrar() {

    console.log(this.registerForm.get('nome').value)

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('nome', this.registerForm.get('nome').value);
    formData.append('email', this.registerForm.get('email').value);
    formData.append('cpf', this.registerForm.get('cpf').value);
    formData.append('telefone', this.registerForm.get('telefone').value);
    formData.append('password', this.registerForm.get('password').value);
    formData.append('file', 'testeFile');

    console.log(formData);

    this.cadastroService.cadastrar(formData).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    })

  }


}
```

The return from the console log is a FormData {}. However, if I give a console log in any registerForm field, the value will be returned correctly. Does anyone know what may be happening in the construction of this request?

My backend Laravel is the logFile of request:

```php
[2020-05-29 03:17:25] local.ALERT: array (
  'data' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Comment: instead of formData in console, can you try individual property ? e.g `console.log(formData.get('email');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Form data is alive. But you can't see its data when using console.log(formData) function.
Instead you can see that data like this.

```
console.log(formData.get('nome'));
console.log(formData.get('email'));
```

Comment: In backend (laravel) that is the logfile:
```php
[2020-05-29 03:17:25] local.ALERT: array (
  'data' => 
  array (
  ),
)  

```